# How do I use QTest::keyClick with control characters?

Tags: user-interface, keyboard-events, qt6, qttest

I am trying to simulate user input to close a window.  I try to use QTest::keyClick(Qt::key::Key_F4, myWidget, Qt::KeyboardModifiers{ Qt::KeyboardModifier::AltModifier }); to simulate the user clicking the Alt+F4 keyboard combo, but it does not work.  I step through the code and it seems like keyClick and similar functions only support ASCII characters.  Is there a way to simulate keyClicks that are control characters?

For more detail into my use case, I want to pop-up a message box when someone closes the window.  I have an event filter that handles this.  I have code to check whether the message box is created, but the test case fails because the event filter fails to determine the event.  I think it has something to do with what I pass into keyClick, but I am unsure.

Comment: I opened up an issue on Qt's bug tracker.  https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-115532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing behavior that my code ultimately did not support.  My eventFilter() method checked for events of type KeyPress, KeyRelease, and Close.  QTest::keyClick() does not trigger any of those.  The way I fixed it was to call QTest::keyPress() to simulate pressing the Alt key and then call QWidget::close() to simulate closing the widget.  This change in the code made my test pass.